# How to get all checkboxes values in Angular (10+)?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I retrieve from the database what options should I show for all companies (only for showing purposes), this is my model:

```
 export class OpcionesModel {
        name: string;
        isActive: boolean;
        id?: string;
        
 }
```

Then, I show all the options that are available (active):

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let option of optionsArray; let i=index">
        <div class="col-4">
            <h5>{{option.name | titlecase}}</h5>
          
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <input type="checkbox">

        </div>
        
    </div>
```

What I want to do is to get all option's names and if its checkbox is checked or not and store that in an array, e.g:

[{'option 1', true}, {'option 2'}, false}, {'option 3', false}...].

EDIT: I've created an array: `checkes: boolean[] =[];`

if I do this `<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="checkes[i]">`, I can get the checkboxes value but I need the option name too.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="isActive"  [(ngModel)]="option.isActive">
    {{ option.name }}
</label>
```

taken from here: https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-deal-with-different-form-controls-in-angular-2

In your ts file, Your `optionsArray` array will be binded and the checked values will be updated when it changes

If you want to map it to an array with a different structure you can use the map method:

```
this.optionsArray.map(oa=> {return { myOptionName:oa.name, active:oa.isActive} })
```

Comment: The first model is only to show what 'options' should I show in the page, don't take that in consideration. I need to get the option name and the checkbox value (t or f) in the same object and then push it into an array. Sorry for the model explanation, my bad.

Comment: When you bind `option.isActive`,  your array keep all the values you need. If you want an array with a different structure, map it. I have updated my answer.